# How to make bare git repository group-writable after pushing?

Tags: git

I have a bare git repository on a server which I access via SSH. I can push and pull just fine. However, the files I push are created on the server with access rights `644`, meaning that only I am allowed to change the files. This is fine as long as I'm the only contributor, but what can I do to allow multiple users to work with the repository? I don't have root rights on the server, so I cannot change any global options.

I was thinking about some hook script to change the file permissions after pushing into the repository.

Is this the preferred way to solve my problem? How exactly should I go forward? Are there other/better solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change folders to 775 and files to 664. After that, you need to configure `core.sharedRepository`.

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html

> When group (or true), the repository is made shareable between several
>   users in a group (making sure all the files and objects are
>   group-writable). When all (or world or everybody), the repository will
>   be readable by all users, additionally to being group-shareable. When
>   umask (or false), git will use permissions reported by umask(2). When
>   0xxx, where 0xxx is an octal number, files in the repository will have
>   this mode value. 0xxx will override user’s umask value (whereas the
>   other options will only override requested parts of the user’s umask
>   value). Examples: 0660 will make the repo read/write-able for the
>   owner and group, but inaccessible to others (equivalent to group
>   unless umask is e.g. 0022). 0640 is a repository that is
>   group-readable but not group-writable. See git-init(1). False by
>   default.

In my team repositories, I set it to `group`. So, my `config` looks like this:

```
sharedRepository = group
```

You do not have rights on the server? That needs to be sorted out unless you plan on sharing your one SSH account with multiple contributors.

Comment: Why do I have to share the SSH account? Each user already has an account on the server. The repository is located at `/home/git/myrepo`, and `/home/git` is group-writable and belongs to group `users`. I would think that using your solution, each user who is member of the `users` group should be able to push to the repo, not?

Comment: You said you do not have rights on the server. What rights are you lacking? If you can control the group settings, then you are good to go. I just had the impression that you'd be putting everyone's public keys into one SSH account.

Comment: I guess you said you do not have `root` privileges, which is fine. You can still have a group. You just need to be able to `chmod` the files first.

Answer (score 0):

The server user is just the owner of the repo's files. The contributors are other users which have access to the server, but not necessarily real system users.

Let's say you have the user `git` on `yourserver.com`, and your repo in `/home/git/yourproject.git`.
In this example, we'll use the authorized_keys method for authenticating your users: you need to add the contributors SSH public keys to the authorized_keys file for the user git (e.g. inside `/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys`).

At this point, the contributors can clone the project down and push changes back up just as easily:

```
$ git clone git@yourserver.com:/home/git/yourproject.git
```

The first time the contributors have to configure their identity:

```
$ git config --global user.email "bob@example.com"
```

With this method, you can quickly get a read/write Git server up and running for a handful of developers, without bothering about file permissions, but tracking individual changes; I always used this setup to configure a git repository.

Comment: This works. People just need to be aware that they are effectively exposing SSH access to all contributors this way. So, trust is important here.

Comment: Absolutely, I agree. This is a configuration suitable for groups of trusted users.